# What is coroutine in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I checked the kotlin coroutine documentation but it's not clear and concise, I need a clear and straight forward explanation on it, Thanks

Comment: What is not clear?

Comment: your question is too broad. narrow your question down by asking specifically what you have tried and what you want to achieve.

Comment: You can't hope to get a clear and straightforward answer because each person misses a different piece of the puzzle, and the entirety of the concept of coroutines simply isn't something that you can describe concisely. So if you expand your question with what you learned and what's still bothering you, then someone may jump in to help.

Answer (score 1):

Coroutine are nothing but light weight threads. They are even lighter than normal threads and therefore you can spawn thousands of coroutines even then it will not cause any memory burden or other performance issues and therefore an ideal choice over normal thread.

Coroutines should be your first choice if you are performing asynchronous tasks for example using RXjava just for the sake of switching between threads. 
I.E.  UI thread and IO thread switching we see in Android app development. Example: performing network task on IO thread and show result on main thread.

Comment: Thanks for your response